# How to create a property class in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I want to create a class which will have two properties, e.g. `key` & `value`.

And I want one method which will give me a `value` based on the `key`.

So what is the code?  I know `Hashtable` but how to implement it in C#? Can I have a `string` as a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Here is the best way implement this (I use Int32 as an example of a type to store):

```
Dictionary<String,Int32> dictionary = new Dictionary<String,Int32>
{
    // this just loads up the list with
    // some dummy data - notice that the
    // key is a string and the value is an int
    { "one", 1 },
    { "two", 2 },
    { "three", 3 },
};
```

Now you can grab values from the Dictionary<,> like this:

```
dictionary["one"]; // returns 1
dictionary["two"]; // returns 2
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Dictionary<string, T>` will do all you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dictionary<string, TypeOfYourVAlue>`

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary(TKey, TValue) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple more implementations as well.  There's the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397728.aspx) which is designed for set operations and the [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(VS.80).aspx) which is an easily serializable hash table.

Answer (score 1):

... and also `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, which is roughly equivalent to `Dictionary<string,string>`, but allows storing multiple string values under the same key value. To quote MSDN documentation:

> This class can be used for headers,
>   query strings and form data.